# ComboBoxEdit in GridControl shows no Popup on Click

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, devexpress, gridcontrol

I have a ComboBoxEdit in a GridControl, which is embedded in a LookUpEdit.
I want that the ComboBoxEdit shows values depending on a "Id" and a converter.

My problem: I can click on the button with the arrow in the ComboBoxEdit, but then there is no opened popup. Seems like the clickevent doesn't fire? Furtheremore in debug mode i can see, that the converter does everything right, but the ComboBoxEdit doesn't show any information about the binded list.

Here is my Code:

```xml
<dxg:GridControl x:Name="PART_GridControl">
  <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
    <dxg:GridColumn Header="Column1" Width="100">
      <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <dxe:ComboBoxEdit x:Name="PART_Editor" DisplayMember="Display" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RowData.Row.Id, Converter={local2:ListConverter}}">
          </dxe:ComboBoxEdit>
        </DataTemplate>
      </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
    </dxg:GridColumn>
    <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="something" Header="Column2" Width="130"/>
    <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="something_else" Header="Column3" Width="100"/>
  </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
  <dxg:GridControl.View>
    <dxg:TableView Name="tv_grid" AutoWidth="True" EditorButtonShowMode="ShowForFocusedRow">
    </dxg:TableView>
  </dxg:GridControl.View>
</dxg:GridControl>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

where is the popup control??
first define your popup control then assign client instance name for it(ex popup),
on combo box value change trigger type below code:
popup.Show();

Answer (score 0):

i think you should set the DisplayValue too if i am not mistaken.

Comment: Could you add more details of why it will work with ?